# C# SelectSingleNode returns null

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, file, svg

I'm trying to get a node out of a .svg file, which has some information in a xml format.
This is my code:

```
                XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
                document.Load(openFileDialog.FileName);
                XmlNamespaceManager xmlnsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);
                xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("inkscape", "http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape");
                xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("sodipodi", "http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd");
                xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
                xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("svg", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");

                XmlNode node = document.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("sodipodi:namedview/g/image]", xmlnsManager);
```

Based on the Microsoft documentation, I also tried:

```
descendant::sodipodi:namedview[sodipodi:g/sodipodi:image]
```

I also tried both versions with and without "sodipodi" before g/ and image.
If I only write "sodipodi:namedview" it finds the node and returns it, but I would prefer to get right to the one I need, instead of iterating over it.
This is a short version of the xml file:

```
<svg
   width="210mm"
   height="297mm"
   viewBox="0 0 210 297"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg5"
   inkscape:version="1.1 (c68e22c387, 2021-05-23)"
   sodipodi:docname="Zeichnung.svg"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="namedview7"
     pagecolor="#505050"
     bordercolor="#eeeeee"
     borderopacity="1"
     inkscape:pageshadow="0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="0.46324355"
     inkscape:cx="616.30648"
     inkscape:cy="601.19564"
     inkscape:window-width="1366"
     inkscape:window-height="705"
     inkscape:window-x="1912"
     inkscape:window-y="101"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1" />
  <defs
     id="defs2">
    <rect
       x="69.078134"
       y="554.78377"
       width="613.06844"
       height="252.56693"
       id="rect1536" />
  </defs>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Ebene 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <image
       width="209.62195"
       height="110.57917"
       preserveAspectRatio="none"
       style="image-rendering:optimizeSpeed"
       xlink:href="Really long base64 string"
       id="image47"
       x="-2.8600111"
       y="-0.1732364" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: As far as I can see, the image is not contained in the namedview element, that is an element without children. In Visual Studio, entering your short xml version and then copying the XPath to the image, I get `/svg:svg/svg:g/svg:image`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @cph Nope, you are right and that fixed it, I was just blind, somehow multiple hours long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. your XML path is wrong: `g` is not a child of `sodipodi:namedview`. They are siblings.
2. the XPath is malformed: remove the trailing ']'  character
3. you have defined a default namespace by declaring `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` (no alias/prefix) on the `svg` element, but you are not qualifying the child types of the declaring node using the default namespace. According to XML namespace rules, the default namespace is "inherited" to all child elements of the parent that defines the namespace (`svg` in this case). The default namespace of an element defines an implicit prefix, that implicitly applies to all child elements..

To be able to qualify your elements using the default namespace, you first must register it

```
xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("default", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
```

where `default` is a random alias to map the default namespace.

After registering the default namespace, modify the XPath to qualify child types of `svg` using the alias.

The fixed XPath would look as followed:

```
XmlNode node = document.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("default:g/default:image", xmlnsManager);
```

Alternatively remove the default namespace declaration `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` from the `svg` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try xmllinq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
            XNamespace nsXlink = doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("xlink");
            XElement image = doc.Descendants(ns + "image").FirstOrDefault();
            double width = (double)image.Attribute("width");
            double height = (double)image.Attribute("height");
            string ratio = (string)image.Attribute("preserveAspectRatio");
            string style = (string)image.Attribute("style");
            string href = (string)image.Attribute(nsXlink + "href");
            string id = (string)image.Attribute("id");
            double x = (double)image.Attribute("x");
            double y = (double)image.Attribute("y");

        }
    }
}
```